# Array of multiple path is not working in Nunjucks for templates and partials

Tags: node.js, gulp, nunjucks

I'm using this gulp plugin to use nunjucks to make HTML management easier.

https://github.com/carlosl/gulp-nunjucks-render

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/templates/*.html')
    .pipe(nunjucksRender({
      path: ['src/templates/'] // String or Array
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

I want to keep my templates and partials in different folders so I tried this to keep as path

```
path: ['src/templates', 'src/partials']
```

but it's not working.

```
Template render error: (unknown path)
  Error: template not found: partials/side_nav.nunjucks
```

My setup
[image: screenshot from my editor]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, the issue is in your `include`. You're already defining your base paths as `'src/templates'` and `'src/partials'`. Now nunchucks is trying to import `src/templates/partials/side_nav.nunjucks` and afterwards `src/partials/partials/side_nav.nunjucks`, which don't exist.

**Solution 1**

So you would have to include it without the `partials` part:

```
{% include "side_nav.nunjucks" %}
```

**Solution 2**

If you want to be explicit about your folders (both templates and partials), you could just set you base path to `src` instead, and include your files like you did:

```
{% extends "templates/layout_with_sidenav.nunjucks" %}
...
{% include "partials/side_nav.nunjucks" %}
```

Comment: I'm extending the template not includes. template won't work in use it with include.

Comment: In that case, use my first solution? Or am I missing something? Or the second one with extends instead of include?

Comment: yes your first solution worked. Though I also wanted to make this work too but it's not working. `'src/pages/**/**/includes/'`

Comment: I have added another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768150/globbing-in-template-path-not-working-in-nunjucks-with-gulp