# Globbing in template path not working in nunjucks with gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, template-engine, nunjucks

I'm using this gulp plugin to use nunjucks to make HTML management easier.

https://github.com/carlosl/gulp-nunjucks-render

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/templates/*.html')
    .pipe(nunjucksRender({
      path: ['src/templates/'] // String or Array
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

I want to keep my templates and partials of specific pages under page's directory in different folders so I tried this to keep the path as

```
path: ['src/templates/', 'src/common-partials/', 'src/pages/**/**/includes/']
```

but it's not working.

```
Template render error: (unknown path)
  Error: template not found: component1.nunjucks
```

My setup

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `path` option doesn't support globbing. You have to pass each path individually:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/templates/*.html')
    .pipe(nunjucksRender({
      path: ['src/templates/', 'src/pages/section_name/sub-page/includes'] 
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

If you really want to use globbing you can use the [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) module to resolve each glob before passing it to `gulp-nunjucks-render`:

```
var glob = require('glob');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  var includeDirs = ['src/templates/', 'src/pages/**/includes'];

  return gulp.src('src/templates/*.html')
    .pipe(nunjucksRender({
      path: includeDirs.reduce(function(dirs, g) {
        return dirs.concat(glob.sync(g));
      }, [])
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the two `/**/**/` might be the issue. The `**` pattern matches multiple levels in a path string, so I'm not really sure what the behavior for two of those in are row should be. The following should match your directory:

```
'src/pages/**/includes/'
```

That is, if nunjucks supports globbing in the first place (I couldn't find any mention of it in the documentation).

Comment: `src/pages/**/includes/` also not working, same error

Comment: Can you try an easier path with globbing? e.g `src/**`. Maybe nunjucks really doesn't support globbing in this case.